# ubuntu sees only one cpu

Tags: 18.04, cpu

I (re)installed ubuntu 18.04 on the second disk of my pc (the first is the native windows 10). I used this [image](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and this [procedure](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) (like I did 6 months ago).

Differently from what I did 6 month ago, now Ubuntu only sees 1 cpu (should be 12), as you can see here.

What can I do ?

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              1
On-line CPU(s) list: 0
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  1
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             2381.617
CPU max MHz:         4100.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4416.00
Virtualisation:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            9216K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d
```

`grep -c GenuineIntel /proc/cpuinfo` returns `1`.

The output of `sudo dmidecode -t processor` is quite correct though: core i7, 6 cores, 12 threads:

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 4, 48 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i7
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: EA 06 09 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 158, Stepping 10
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Voltage: 0.8 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 8300 MHz
    Current Speed: 2100 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x001D
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x001E
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x001F
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 6
    Core Enabled: 6
    Thread Count: 12
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control
```

But then why do I see `htop` showing only 1 CPU again ?

[image]

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -c GenuineIntel`

Comment: You could also add the output of `sudo dmidecode -t processor`

Comment: @vidarlo the output is 1.

Comment: Did you tried to boot the Ubuntu 18.04 LiveCD/USB and check number of CPU cores from it?

Comment: @N0rbert yes, it's still 1